# Ищу "прообраз" слов

Tags: словообразование, семантика, фонетика

Неожиданно вышла на созвучие слов «**шкворчать**», «**сковорода**» и... «**скворец**».

Это лишь фонетическое сходство — или общие истоки словообразования? 
И если второе — **каков изначальный смысл** их общего корня?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачастую звуки, производимые феноменами, порождают определяющие их слова: мяуканье, гавканье, улюлюканье, кудахтанье. «Шкварчать» - вариться с шипением. Что такое «шкварки» - это кусочки сала не просто прожаренные, а протопленные в собственном соку. Толковый словарь Даля: сковорода
или сковородка ж. сковрада церк., кухонная посуда, для жарения, пряжения; железная и чугунная тарелка. СКВАРА ж. церк. огонь, пламя, огненный жупел; горение и смрад. Небо от сквары Божества Его вскурится, Пролог. Скварами жертв мерзких, Минеи. || Церк. скверна; это значение (Шмквч.) должно быть ближе к коренному. || Сквара и скварка мн. зап. и южн. шквара, вышкварки, вытопки или перегорелые остатки на салотопне. Вероятно малорос. шкварить и шпарить, а затем и парить, пар, того же корня; может быть отсюда же и скаред, скверный, скверна, сковорода и пр. Сковрадный говор. вм. скаредный: На едино бо от сковрадных во ангелех онех есть, стар.http://slovari.yandex.ru/~книги/Толковый%20словарь%20Даля/ «Скворец, вероятнее всего, так же слово звукоподражательное. Звуки эта птица издаёт различные, в том числе и свистящий «скв- скв», если внимательно прислушаться. Итак, какой вывод можно из всего вышесказанного сделать: слова «шкварчать» и «скворец» - связаны между собой лишь тем, что оба являются звукоподражательными, не более того. А вот со «сковородой» не всё так просто, как видим по Далю. Это и огонь,  с которым сковорода связана непосредственно, и звук жарения – шкварчания, который так же зачастую производит сковорода.

Comment: Благодарю Вас - очень любопытные параллели! 

Интересно было бы услышать ещё какие-нибудь версии... )

Comment: В беларусском языке скворец - это шпак почему-то. Интересно почему?

Comment: По начальному сочетанию "шп" напомнило польскую — и возможно, немецкую — фонетику.

Посмотрела в словаре: по-польски скворец = szpak.

К сожалению, я не сильна в подробностях этого языка и отследить "исторические корни" слова не удалось...

Comment: Из СЛОВОПЕДИИ:

ШПАК
"скворец", южн., зап. (Даль), уменьш. шпачок, укр., блр. шпак, чеш. sраcеk, польск. szpak, szрасzеk. Скорее всего вторичное, обратное образование от уменьш. sраcеk, которое развилось из нов.-в.-н. Sраtz "воробей", ср.-в.-н. spatz, первонач. ласкат. формы от д.-в.-н. sраrо "воробей"; см. Мi. ЕW 341; Голуб – Копечный 373. Менее убедительно предположение о заимствовании из голл. sресht "дятел" (Горяев, ЭС 425) или о праслав. происхождении (Брюкнер 551), причем даже нем. Sраtz и т. д. рассматриваются как заимств. из слав. (ошибочно также и Ильинский, ИОРЯС 20, 4, 182).