# Шкварчать или шкворчать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Наткнулась на огромное количество споров об употреблении этих слов. Хотелось бы послушать обоснование того или иного написания.
Контекст: "Шкв(а/о)рчать на сковороде".

Comment: [Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33266/%d0%98%d1%89%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2) можно посмотреть достаточно подробный разбор.

Comment: @grizzly: как Вы так делаете в комментариях гиперссылки?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Подчёркнутое слово пишу в квадратных скобках, а саму ссылку сразу после него в круглых: [подчёркнутые слова](адрес). Подробнее написано в справке (кнопка "справка" появляется справа возле комментария, когда Вы начинаете комментировать).

Comment: @grizzly: спасибо! Я пробовал так, но оказалось, что проходит только с https.

Answer (score 1):

«Шкварчать», потому что есть однокоренное слово *шквáрки*.